# Is there a design pattern for an informational pane?

Tags: design-patterns

What I'm picturing is a side panel that updates with region-specific information as I mouse over portions of the form. Is there a name for this pattern?

It's like a [Two-panel Selector](http://quince.infragistics.com/#/Search%24tag=Browse/ViewPattern%24pattern=Two-Panel+Selector&lang=en), but not selecting or navigating anything, just providing information. I seem to recall seeing it in some applications when I open help.

Comment: At least half of the name is "context sensitive".  I think you have options for what word you put after that (properties, information, data).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe i'd call that a detail pane layout.  Mouse over or focus on something in the left pane and get information regarding your selection in a pane on the right.

[image: a screenshot from visual explain for postgresql that shows a view pane on the left and a details pane on the right]

Answer (score 2):

Well, imo its just a sort of tooltips, say static tooltip.

Nice working example to refer: http://register.wildapricot.com/ 
 
Tooltip on the right side is fixed, and changes text every time one of fields get hovered or got focus.

Comment: I like this as well, in fact better than my original idea, but it's not what I was trying to describe. Thanks though :)